# Can't include BP class to CPP class in UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have C++ Component file, and I need to attach one `Actor` to `SkeletalMesh` from my `Blueprint Class` ( Owner of component ).I don't know how to include not C++ class, to my C++ code. For Example to include C++ class from similar folder I am using `#include "ClassName.h"`. Is it possible to include BP Class?

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I got this right (correct me if I'm wrong).

There are H files that Unreal provides for these kind of general cases, so you can handle the appropriate types while coding.

If you're trying to include a custom Blueprint class into your C++ code, those classes are generated and if you check your World Outliner while running your game, you'll notice the classes being called with a suffix "_C". That's the Blueprint-based generated C class.

If that's the case you can refactor this by creating base classes in C++ and reparenting the Blueprint classes you created to those ones, who provide the specific functions you need. Then, in C++ you just create a bunch of handy .h files you can include that lists those classes.